# Bootstrap 4 input-group-append not working

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

Using the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
      crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- jQuery libraries -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    </main><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I actually render the page, the `input-group-append` section doesn't seem to work. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Rendered page screenshot]

However, this clearly doesn't look like the examples [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/).

Not sure what I should be doing differently here, is this a bug with the Bootstrap 4.0 Beta?

Quick additional note, in case it's relevant somehow, I'm using Django 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There wasn't any bugs.

You included a lot of unnecessaries. The `jQuery` are making lots of disruption. Be careful when adding scripts that may come into conflict. Refer to my code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>


</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</main><!-- /.container -->

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Comment: It seems, that 'prepend' style is first introduced in **4.0.0-beta.3**
Original code uses previous version **4.0.0-beta.2**, where 'prepend' doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 22):

I just encountered this one today. I double checked my styles and scripts and everything is good. Instead of using the append and preped, I used the input-**group-addon** and **input-group-btn**.

Please see this [link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#multiple-addons).

Comment: This seemed to work for me as well, rather than using what is currently shown in the official documentation

Comment: Could this have to do with using bootstrap css instead of bootstrap js?

Comment: indeed worked for me too. I guess its an issue with the bootstrap alpa 4 version

Comment: -append and -prepend were added in 4.0 Beta 3. If you are on one of those versions, this answer will work, but as soon as you upgrade (to 4.1 at the time of this writing), it will quit working.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 4 got out of alpha (4.1 at the time of this answer) and the following should work now:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
        <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

So, use class `input-group-btn` along with `input-group-prepend` (or `input-group-prepend`) and `input-group-text`.

Check version 4.1 docs for Input Group [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/).

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else presents the same issue, I did it just this way

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert password...">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-show-psw" type="button">show</button>
</div>
```

Just avoid using `input-group-append` or anything else. Only declared the `input-group` in the group itself.

Anyway, I did not see this mention to this way in the official doc at [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/)

Comment: Because this isn't using bootstrap styles. They would require additional classes. This doesn't use Bootstrap at all for the append, other than the `.input-group` class trying to keep it all on the same line if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5 according this link [From bootsrap documents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/)

use like this

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
</div>
```

Or a complete Example :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="input-group mb-3"> <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"> <span class="input-group-text">.00</span> </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens if u add admin-lte css and bootstrap css both. It worked after removing bootstrap css